# How to oconsume JWT's from identityServer in ASP.NET REST API

Tags: asp.net, api, rest, thinktecture-ident-server

I have spent days trying to get up to speed on this but everything has changed since I last touched a web project and I'm utterly overwhelmed right now, and getting nowhere. I'm trying to put together the pieces for an implicit grant flow - just a simple web API that respects the tokens issued by my local instance of I.S.

I have been able to download and configure I.S. v2 locally. I've got it issuing authentication tokens in JWT format after sending the browser to the login page. I can see the token info come back as part of the redirect URL from IS, like 'access_token=...&token_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:jwt&expires_in=599'.

So now I need to configure my asp.net API site to accept these tokens, and I can't figure out how. As I said, I haven't done web work in a while so Owin, WIF, and many more things involved here are brand new to me all at once.

What are the key steps I need to do have my API site accept these tokens? I guess I'm not sure what packages to include, what goes into the web.config related to the WIF aspect, do I need to write any code to make it work, or should there be some combination of config settings that just activate it? Do I need to create a custom ClaimsAuhtorizationManager?

Please, I'm bad shape here, I've been looking at this stuff for days and I still don't know enough to even figure out what else to try. Every sample I've found has had a significant different from my situation, rendering it unhelpful to me (most point to Azure or ADFS, or use the old classes which are now deprecated). It's not for a lack of effort, I've been reading everything I can get my hands on and scouring the web for days.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

IdSrv issues standard JWT tokens - so there is nothing specific to it.

You can e.g. use the JWT handler from Microsoft. For Web API v2 the typical way would be to use the JWT middleware - here is a sample:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.AuthorizationServer/blob/master/samples/Flows/ResourceServer%20(Web%20API%20v2)/App_Start/AuthConfig.cs